# > in a HTML comment breaks the comment

Tags: bug, markdown

When a `>` is encountered in a HTML comment the comment breaks.
Take the following markdown source:

```
<!--
Here is an example of this working fine.

And a second line to show that's not the problem.
-->

<!--
This isn't visible like you would expect.

> Everything from here is visible.
-->
```

Which renders as:

---

Everything from here is visible.
-->

---

Here is an example of the above part of the question in the preview screen.

> [image: Preview showing comment is escaped.]

There are two comments, one completely hidden the other partially visible.

This means I can't hide some HTML used to get a render. This means if I, or others, need to update the render we either don't have the HTML available or I have to clutter the post.

Comment: This seems like a fault in SE's renderer. I've tried the markup in a normal HTML document in Chrome and Edge and the text disappears as expected.

Comment: Confirmed broken, fails [example at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_comments.asp):

`<!-- Do not display this image at the moment
<img border="0" src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli">
-->`

Shows "-->".

Comment: From the [canonical HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#comments), a single `>` character is allowed in comments.

Comment: [Here's a link to the CommonMark spec's section on HTML comments](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#html-comment), and [here's a link to the CommonMark playground showing CommonMark-compliant behaviour](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3C!--%0A%3E%20hello%20world%20from%20block%20quote%20inside%20HTML%20comment%0A--%3E%0A%3E%20hello%20world%20from%20block%20quote%20after%20HTML%20comment%0A).